# Loading Local HTML from another HTML file - React native Android

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I am loading the webview with local file by using below code,

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={["*"]}
    allowFileAccess={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    androidLayerType={"hardware"}
    source={Platform.OS === "android" ? { uri: "file:///android_asset/about.html" } : require("./constants/about.html")}
 />
```

Here, the "about.html" internally refers one another HTML file.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        p {
            color:black;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Welcome</p>
   <p>
     Referring another Local HTML<a target="_blank" href=“another_Local.html">link</a>.
 </p>

</body>
```

But this implementation is working fine iOS Platform, but the same is not working in Android. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use react-native-fs or expo-file-system to load any files in your react-native app.